# What is the purpose of DECREQTPARM in VT100?

Tags: terminal, terminal-emulator, vt100

I'm implementing a terminal emulator for the ESP8266 ("ESPTerm"), and going through the xterm manpage for reference, as well as the old VTxxx reference manuals.

I've implemented `DECREQTPARM`. But now am asking myself a question: What's this good for?

Clearly, once you are able to send the query and get a response, you already know the right baud rate, parity and byte length. Was this ever used for anything, and is it of any use today?

The only piece of the information worth querying for is the `{flags}` value, but that's only used for some expansion board.

Here is what I found, for reference:

```
DECREQTPARM     Request Terminal Parameters

        <ESC>[ {Ps} x

        The host sends this sequence to request the VT100 to send a DECREPTPARM
        sequence back.  {Ps} can be either 0 or 1.  If 0, the terminal will be
        allowed to send unsolicited DECREPTPARMs.  These reports will be
        generated each time the terminal exits the SET-UP mode.  If {Ps} is 1,
        then the terminal will only generate DECREPTPARMs in response to a
        request.


DECREPTPARM     Report Terminal Parameters      VT100 to Host

        <ESC>[ {sol} ; {par} ; {nbits} ; {xspd} ; {rspd} ; {cmul} ; {flags} x

        This sequence is generated by the VT100 to notify the host of the
        status of selected terminal parameters.  The status sequence may be
        sent when requested by the host (via DECREQTPARM) or at the terminal's
        discretion.  On power up or reset, the VT100 is inhibited from sending
        unsolicited reports.

        The meanings of the sequence paramters are:

        Parameter       Value   Meaning
        ------------------------------------------------------------------
          {sol}           1     This message is a report.
                          2     This message is a report, and the terminal is
                                only reporting on request.

          {par}           1     No parity set
                          4     Parity set and odd
                          5     Parity set and even

         {nbits}          1     8 bits per character
                          2     7 bits per character

         {xspd}           0     Speed set to 50 bps
         -and-            8     Speed set to 75 bps
         {rspd}          16     Speed set to 110 bps
                         24     Speed set to 134.5 bps
         {xspd}=         32     Speed set to 150 bps
          Transmit       40     Speed set to 200 bps
          Speed          48     Speed set to 300 bps
                         56     Speed set to 600 bps
         {rspd}=         64     Speed set to 1200 bps
          Recieve        72     Speed set to 1800 bps
          Speed          80     Speed set to 2000 bps
                         88     Speed set to 2400 bps
                         96     Speed set to 3600 bps
                        104     Speed set to 4800 bps
                        112     Speed set to 9600 bps
                        120     Speed set tp 19200 bps

        {cmul}            1     The bit rate multiplier is 16

        {flags}        0-15     This value communicates the four switch values
                                in block 5 of SET-UP B, which are only visible
                                to the user when an STP option is installed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short: aside from the obvious, not much use

longer:

DEC's engineers didn't design the VT100 with the foreknowledge that you could just run **`stty`** and get the information, and with [*autobauding* modems](https://books.google.com/books?id=AcGFlqSqNEUC&pg=PA84&lpg=PA84&dq=autobauding%20modem&source=bl&ots=xNWR8a2Qtg&sig=T1giAhsJe97C3-6JmPvHVM4i5KI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiv0Zv6mOnVAhUp2oMKHVtTAC4Q6AEIWDAJ#v=onepage&q=autobauding%20modem&f=false) (cited there as *"by the early 1980s"*, which means that the feature was commercially available **before**), it's certainly possible that you wouldn't really know what your real line speed was.  Nor would you know the other details of the serial connection as seen by your DEC computer.

Some of DEC's later systems (such as VMS) had a way to show some of the information, e.g., [**`show term`**](http://knowledge.digi.com/articles/Knowledge_Base_Article/Application-Notes-VMS-Async-Port-Configuration).

Comment: didn't know about autobauding, that's interesting! thanks